# WCF Strong Typed Collections corrupted name on client

Tags: wcf, collections, asmx, corrupt

I have an existing web service (ASMX) which exposes a service FooService with a method called `SelectPaged`. This method returns a `PagedList<FooDTO>`. In ASMX this is converted to a `PagedListOfFooDTO` and that works fine.

However now I have moved to WCF (in fact exposing both ASMX and WCF) and my `PagedListOfFooDTO` is getting corrupted somewhere. If I add a wcf service reference and an asmx web reference to a client app and look at the service proxy in the client through the object browser, I see asmx has proxied a type called `PagedListOfFooDTO`. But doing the same thing for the WCF proxy in the object browser shows a type called `PagedListOfxhHzuSy2`. Something is obviously going wrong when WCF is creating the proxy for this collection type. Has anyone seen this behaviour before. `FooDTO` is decorated with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` appropriately.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look there : 
http://flylib.com/books/en/2.713.1.36/1/

Comment: This is the fix. The corruption is a hash 'by design'. Setting a name for the type resolves the issue. Detail is in Vivien's link. Many thanks.